# SELECT MAX DATE FROM MULTIPLE DATES

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

this is my case:

I have 2 tables `SKU` & `Disco_Dates`.

In both tables there is a similar field.

```
SKU.[MFG_PART_NUMBER] = Disco_Dates.[MATERIAL]
```

I need to know the max DATE_UPDATE available for each MFG_PART_NUMBER

```
DISCO_DATE TABLE

+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| MATERIAL    |DISCO_DATE             | DATE_UPDATE           | 
+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|T6C25AW#ABC  |NULL                   |2016-09-14 11:15:03.587|
|T6C25AW#ABC  |2016-10-28 00:00:00.000|2016-09-21 13:45:03.591| 
|T6C25AW#ABC  |2016-10-31 00:00:00.000|2016-09-30 12:38:08.990| 
+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+

SKU TABLE

+---------------+
|MFG_PART_NUMBER| 
+---------------+
|T6C25AW#ABC    |
|G2F32UC#ABC    |
+---------------+
```

SQL QUERY

```
SELECT
 t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER]
,t2.[DISCO_DATE]
,MAX (t2.[DATE_UPDATE]) as DATE_UPDATE

FROM Test.dbo.SKU t1

LEFT JOIN Test.dbo.Tbl_Disco_Dates t2
ON [MFG_PART_NUMBER] = [MATERIAL]

WHERE t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER] = 'T6C25AW#ABC'

group by 
  t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER]
 ,t2.[DISCO_DATE]
```

My current result is giving me all 3 rows.

This is what I need.

```
+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|MFG_PART_NUMBER |DISCO_DATE             | DATE_UPDATE           |  
+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|T6C25AW#ABC     |2016-10-31 00:00:00.000|2016-09-30 12:38:08.990| 
+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
 t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER]
,t2.[DISCO_DATE]
,t2.[DATE_UPDATE] as DATE_UPDATE

FROM Test.dbo.SKU t1

LEFT JOIN Test.dbo.Tbl_Disco_Dates t2
ON [MFG_PART_NUMBER] = [MATERIAL]

WHERE t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER] = 'T6C25AW#ABC'
      AND t2.[DATE_UPDATE] = (SELECT MAX(t2.[DATE_UPDATE] FROM Test.dbo.Tbl_Disco_Dates t2)
```

Comment: Pretty close to the desired result. But it led me to find the answer

      SELECT
      t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER]
     ,t2.[DISCO_DATE]
     ,t2.[DATE_UPDATE] as DATE_UPDATE

     FROM Test.dbo.SKU t1

     LEFT JOIN Test.dbo.Tbl_Disco_Dates t2
     ON [MFG_PART_NUMBER] = [MATERIAL]

     WHERE t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER] = 'T6C25AW#ABC'
      AND t2.[DATE_UPDATE] = (SELECT MAX(t2.[DATE_UPDATE])   FROM Test.dbo.Tbl_Disco_Dates t2)

     group by 
      t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER]
     ,t2.[DISCO_DATE]
     ,t2.[DATE_UPDATE]

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot MAX has to be in a SELECT statement

Comment: Does it still need the group by if you do it this way?

Comment: @Kris Good tip, Group by is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
 declare @maxdate datetime
 select @maxdate = max(t2.[DATE_UPDATE]) FROM Test.dbo.SKU
 select * from ( SELECT
  t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER]
 ,t2.[DISCO_DATE]
  , DATE_UPDATE

  FROM Test.dbo.SKU  where DATE_UPDATE=   @maxdate)   t1 
  LEFT JOIN Test.dbo.Tbl_Disco_Dates t2
   ON t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER] = t2.[MATERIAL]

  WHERE t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER] = 'T6C25AW#ABC'

  group by 
 t1.[MFG_PART_NUMBER]
 ,t2.[DISCO_DATE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a simple `GROUP BY` query work:

```
SELECT MATERIAL,
       MAX(DISCO_DATE) AS DISCO_DATE,
       MAX(DATE_UPDATE) AS DATE_UPDATE
FROM Test.dbo.Tbl_Disco_Dates
GROUP BY MATERIAL
```